# Find all integers in list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, int

Given this list of string values:

`"12345"`, `"6789a"`, `"9876"`, `"23467b"`

How do we use a Linq statement in C# to select only the integers? In other words, we only want to return `12345` and `9876`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can filter your entries based on the return value of the [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method:

```
int temp;
list.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out temp));
```

Comment: The behaviour of the value of `temp` is an undocumented implementation detail and could change in future. I prefer [an extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19091443/284240) instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Valid point. However, the solution above remains correct as long as the final value of `temp` is not used by the subsequent code. One could enclose the above code snippet in a dedicated statement block to enforce this.

Answer (score 6):

Filter the list down to only those strings all characters of which are digits:

```
var filtered = list.Where(s => s.All(char.IsDigit));
```

An alternative is to use `int.TryParse` as the filtering function, which has a number of subtle differences in behavior (the rules for what a valid integer is allow more than just digits, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)).

If you want the results typed as integers, follow this up with `.Select(int.Parse)`.

Comment: This would miss negative values, and integers with leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Douglas: There is an explicit mention of that in the answer; I have added a link to the docs.

Comment: Yes, I was summarizing the main differences that one might expect to come across. On the other hand, this approach is likely to be more efficient than `int.TryParse` if the all-digit assumption is valid for the OP's data.

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = strings.Where(str => str.All(Char.IsDigit))
    .Select(str => int.Parse(str));
```

This selects only strings where all chars are digits. Then it parses them to `int`.

A better way is to use this extension:

```
public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Then you can use this query:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = strings.Select(str => str.TryGetInt())
    .Where(nullableInt => nullableInt.HasValue)
    .Select(nullableInt => nullableInt.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `TryParse` method of `int` is the most reliable indicator that you have a proper number.

Use it like this:

```
int number = 0;
var selected = list.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out number)).ToList();
```